# setted cursor on form wont show up on controls

Tags: forms, delphi, grid, cursor, controls

I use Delphi xe-8 and I use thread for queries and I want to show an hourglass cursor while my thread is working.

I'm setting my cursor to hourglass but when I hover on controls on the form, for example over a grid, the cursor appears as the default; the cursor only changes when I hover over the form itself. What I want to do is to show an hourglass cursor over just the form and any controls on the form, but not the rest of the application.

I tried to set Screen.Cursor to crHourGlass but then it is for the whole application, so it is an hourglass even if I'm hovering on another form.

Is it possible to do that? If it is how can i do that?

Comment: Threads don't have cursors. If you want each control to have the same cursor, you need to set it for each control. If you do so, make sure you include a try..finally to make sure they all get set back.

Comment: You need to set [`Screen.Cursor`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Berlin/en/Vcl.Forms.TScreen.Cursor)

Comment: @FreeConsulting: No, you don't, and the poster said they've tried that already.

Comment: Then you both need to read dat fine manual.

Comment: @KenWhite "*you need to set it for each control*" - actually, you don't. See the update I just made to my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the mouse is over a given `TWinControl`, the OS sends it a `WM_SETCURSOR` message requesting it to set the onscreen cursor icon.  The VCL's default processing of that message goes like this:

1. if the `Screen.Cursor` is not `crDefault`, that is the cursor used.
2. otherwise, if the `TWinControl` has a `TGraphicControl` child underneath the mouse, and its `Cursor` is not `crDefault`, that is the cursor used.
3. otherwise, if the `TWinControl`'s own `Cursor` is not `crDefault`, that is the cursor used.
4. otherwise, the message is passed to the parent window.  Repeat steps 2-3.

So, to do what you are asking for, try setting the Form's `Cursor` to the desired value, and make sure all child controls on the Form have their `Cursor` set to `crDefault`.

If that is not an option for you, or if it doesn't work, you can instead have your Form class override its virtual `WndProc()` method (or use a [`message` method](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Methods_(Delphi)#Message_Methods)) to handle the `WM_SETCURSOR` message directly.  Call the `inherited` handler first, and if the message's `Result` is `FALSE` and the worker thread is running then call the Win32 API `SetCursor()` function to set your desired cursor icon, and set the message's `Result` to `TRUE`, eg:

```pascal
protected
  procedure WndProc(var Message: TMessage); override;

...

procedure TMyForm.WndProc(var Message: TMessage);
begin
  inherited;
  if (Message.Msg = WM_SETCURSOR) and (Message.Result = 0) and (Thread is Running) then
  begin
    Windows.SetCursor(Screen.Cursors[crHourGlass]);
    Message.Result := 1;
  end;
end;
```

Or

```pascal
private
  procedure WMSetCursor(var Message: TMessage); message WM_SETCURSOR;

...

procedure TMyForm.WMSetCursor(var Message: TMessage);
begin
  inherited;
  if (Message.Result = 0) and (Thread is Running) then
  begin
    Windows.SetCursor(Screen.Cursors[crHourGlass]);
    Message.Result := 1;
  end;
end;
```

This way, `Screen.Cursor` and individual `TControl.Cursor` properties still take priority, but if the cursor remains unchanged (ie, all of the properties are `crDefault`) then you can change the cursor for the entire Form as a whole, without affecting other Forms.

Comment: That does not work. The child controls change the cursor to crDefault, they do not inherit the Form cursor. As Ken said above you need to set all the child controls to the cursor that you want.

Comment: @SoftDeveloper I have updated my answer.  I added a different option - override `WndProc` - and I have tested it to make sure it actually works, which it does. No need to set the `Cursor` on all child controls to the same value, like Ken suggested.

Comment: Thanks for the response and I get the idea, however the code snippet seems to be a strange mixture of Delphi and C++ and cannot just be pasted into a form

Comment: @SoftDeveloper fixed